# I'm trying to use backgroundworker but it doesn't work - why?

Tags: c#

This is the code of the `DoWork` event the `ProgressChanged` event and the `RunWorkerCompleted` event. The problem is that the progressBar is getting to 100% much faster before the function process operation is end. So when the progressBar is up to 100% I'm getting error exception since the progressBar can't be 101%

I need somehow to make that the progressBar will get progress according to the function process / progress. I guess that something is wrong with my calculation in the `DoWork` event.

In the `Form1` top I added:

```
Int i;
```

In the constructor I did:

```
i = 0;

backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
```

And this is the events of the `Backgroundworker`:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
   //int currentLength;
   //int currentIndex;
   //int lastIndex = 0;
   string startTag = "T256=\"";
   string endTag = "\"";
   int startTagWidth = startTag.Length;
   //int endTagWidth = endTag.Length;
   int index = 0;

   h = new StreamReader(@"d:\DeponiaSplit\testingdeponias_Translated.txt");

   while ((line = h.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
      if (index > f.LastIndexOf(startTag))
      {
         break;
      }

      int startTagIndex = f.IndexOf(startTag, index);
      int stringIndex = startTagIndex + startTagWidth;
      index = stringIndex;
      int endTagIndex = f.IndexOf(endTag, index);
      int stringLength = endTagIndex - stringIndex;

      if (stringLength != 0)
      {
         string test = f.Substring(stringIndex, stringLength);
         f = f.Substring(0, stringIndex) + line + f.Substring(stringIndex + stringLength);

         if (listBox1.InvokeRequired)
         {
            textBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { textBox1.Text = line; }));
         }

         i = i + 1;
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
         worker.ReportProgress((i * 1));
      }
   }

   h.Close();

   StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"D:\New folder (24)\000004aa.xml");
   w.AutoFlush = true;
   w.Write(f);
   w.Close();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //this.progressBar1.Text = (e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%");
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   if ((e.Cancelled == true))
   {
      this.progressBar1.Text = "Canceled!";
   }
   else if (!(e.Error == null))
   {
      this.progressBar1.Text = ("Error: " + e.Error.Message);
   } 
   else
   {
       this.progressBar1.Text = "Done!";
   }
}
```

Why doesn't it work correctly?

**Working using FileStream**

Now I wanted to add to the progressBar a label which will show `%` and the label will move according to the progressBar I don't want to disable the progressBar green color progress just to add `%` and show the numbers in percentages.

So in the `ProgressChanged` event I did :

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    label3.Text = (e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%");
}
```

But it doesn't work - the `label13` doesn't move only the % changed to 1. I want to see something like 1%...2%...3%... and so on. How can I do it?

Comment: So from I understand here you have a file which you are reading line by line and want to update the progress bar whenever a line is read?

Comment: If you want to shorten `does not` - then you get `doesn't` - and not `dosent` as you constantly used.

Comment: Am I getting your new question right: The label shows %, 1, 2, 3 instead of 1%, 2%, 3%? Maybe the label.Width is not correct, so the content is cut off? You could try label.AutoSize ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use `File.ReadAllLines`, it returns an array of strings. You could report your progress as the percentage of the line you are processing to the total number of lines:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"d:\DeponiaSplit\testingdeponias_Translated.txt"); 
// ...
worker.ReportProgress(i * 100 / lines.Length);
```

Comment: Right idea, but due to integer division, your code will always give zero.  Try `i * 100 / lines.Length` instead.

Comment: I did it this way in the end:  using (var fs = new FileStream(@"d:\DeponiaSplit\testingdeponias_Translated.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {

                using (var h = new StreamReader(fs))
                {

                    string line;

                    while ((line = h.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {

                        int percent = (int)(fs.Position * 100 / fs.Length);
                        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(percent); and its working . Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

The "ReportProgress()" method is reporting "i" right after "i" has been incremented with the "i+1" statment. i is a variable that is incremented every time you have found a string that has matched your provided parameters.  I think the problem here is that you are reporting an integer without context.  Do you know how many lines total in the file contain a string that matches your parameters.  I would suggest reporting (i/totalNumLinesMatchingParameters) * 100.  This would report a number in terms of percentage.  However, this does not include the action of writing the File.  So you may want to scale the above differently if you intend to include the action of writing the File in your progress bar/progress bar label...

Comment: Its working ! i used FileStream. Now i updated my main question added another question.